# square number year, cube number day, when was I born?

Tags: riddle, calculation-puzzle

At the year of a square number,
My age will be it's square root.
At the day of a cube number,
my month is it's cube root.
add the day and the month make them thirsty.

I'm still alive, when was I born ? (dd/mm/yyyy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My attempt:

> 27/03/1980, 2025 is 45 squared, 27 is a cube, and 27+3=30 (thir*s*ty)

Comment: I'm still alive.. as per your answer, how is it possible?... It is still 2016.

Comment: my age **will** be (45) @SathiReddy

Comment: @SathiReddy. He has asked "At the year of a square number My age will be its SquareRoot", So that only he has given this answer.

Comment: @Jon Mark Perry.. well..

Comment: as he was born 27/03/1980, in 45 years it will be 2025, which is 45^2. He is currently 36. @SathiReddy

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> 27/03/1980 square root of 2025 = 45  (still alive and so he will be 45 years in 2025)
>  2025 - 45 = 1980

Cuberoot(Day) = month. Here there are two possibilities

> 1. cuberoot(27) = 3
>  2. cuberoot (8) = 2.
>  But we need day + month = 30. So i take day as 27 and month as 3.

Comment: Wrong, because if 1936, my age is 80 now, but the question say **will be** it's square root.

Comment: Yes, mistake in year..

Comment: @Jamal Senjaya.. Good question..please continue this..

Answer (score 0):

> My birth day is 27/03/1980.. In 2025 I will be 45... So my birth year is 1980... Similarly 3 is cube root of 27...

Comment: I think downvoting a new member's answer is quite rude. I give +1 as welcome